# Angular Css styling overflow scroll

Tags: css, angular

I am trying an angular table to display data, I can able to produce data but when I try to apply vertical and horizontal scrolling, I want to apply scroll bars for the table rather than for the page, I could able to get it done but for whenever scroll bar is applied, table body columns are getting disturbed as below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lss9nk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remplace

```
     overflow: auto;
```

with

```
    overflow: overlay;
```

like :

```
    table thead, table tbody, .trClass {
       width: 100%;
       display: block;
       /* overflow: auto; */
       overflow: overlay;
       /*overflow-y: scroll;*/ 
    }
```

Comment: This works partially. scrollbar area is having many unwanted scroll icons as https://angular-lss9nk.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Added the picture in quesiton, please find it.
https://angular-lss9nk.stackblitz.io/
OR https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lss9nk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Ok, try to delete overflow-y: scroll; like my post

Comment: Yes that is working thank you, one clarificaiton, will "overlay" make horizontal scrollbar also working

Comment: Np ! you can check https://material.angular.io/ to use some nice graphic component like : Table, button and other. If you want